# ReactJS hooks re-render functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When using functional component, dropdown re-render every time I set a state and the value in the dropdown does not change.

Edit:
I am using semantic ui react library. (https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-subcomponent-control)

```
const Table = () => {
    const [tickers, setTickers] = useState("")
    const test = [{
        key: 1,
        text: "0001",
        value: "0001"
    },{
        key: 2,
        text: "0002",
        value: "0002"
    }]
    const DropdownSelection = () => {
        return (
            <Form.Select
                fluid
                search
                multiple
                name="ticker"
                options={test}
                onChange={(e, { value }) => setTickers(value)}
                placeholder="Tickers"
            />
            )
    }

    return(
            <Form>
                    <DropdownSelection />
            </Form>)
```

However, it works when I put the component inside the return function. Although dropdown still being re-rendered, but the value is in it.

```
const Table = () => {
    const [tickers, setTickers] = useState("")
    const test = [{
        key: 1,
        text: "0001",
        value: "0001"
    },{
        key: 2,
        text: "0002",
        value: "0002"
    }]
    return(
           <Form>
               <Form.Select
                fluid
                search
                multiple
                name="ticker"
                options={test}
                onChange={(e, { value }) => setTickers(value)}
                placeholder="Tickers"
               />
           </Form>)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is `tickersDropdown`? You're not using the state anywhere so why would re-rendering change anything?

Comment: @GuyIncognito Apologies, I have edited my question.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I am using semantic react library to populate the dropdown menu (https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-subcomponent-control). The first code works fine in Class but it is not working in functional component.

Comment: *"What could be the problem?"* that this line `const DropdownSelection = () => { ... }` inside the render function creates a new component on every render. not a new instance, an entirely new component. So on every render you unmount the old select and mount an entirely new one that just happens to look alike.

Comment: Each time `Table` runs, you're essentially redeclaring the component `DropdownSelection` "class". Move it outside `Table`.

Comment: Mind posting as answer for me to mark as accepted? Thank you :)